# Strange square characters in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I was testing a website I'm developing in Firefox ( latest version + nightly), and I have weird squares around text :

[image]

When I try to copy - paste it, it seems to be an empty space

I use this doctype, like other website I develop...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
[....]
```

Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SCr7F/

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful, also a missing glyph can cause that square..

Comment: I think this can happen when you don't have support for other languages installed

Comment: I think I resolved it by checking on my font book on Mac OS. I had a conflict with the Garamond font. I resolved it and It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by checking on my font book on Mac OS. I had a conflict with the Garamond font. I resolved it and It works now. I also changed the name of the Garamond font in my css, the first letter needed to be uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

The "strange square" is the font's default character, which is used as a placeholder for characters (codepoints) for which the font does not have a corresponding glyph. The solution is to use a different font, or eliminate those characters.